# Updating in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to insert or replace an exit record inside sqlite but if the record is found it's being completely replaced but i want the int values to be incremented.

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO persons (id, username, points, score) VALUES ('id', 'username', 10, 2)
```

If the record exists I want to be able to grab the existing points and level and add onto them with new values incoming, how do I do this? I am stuck

Comment: You have to do it in three steps.  If the record exists, do UPDATE, otherwise do INSERT.

Comment: How exactly do I do that (new to this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just like updating a dictionary in Python.  If the record doesn't exist, you create it, otherwise, you update it.

```
cur.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM persons WHERE id=?;', (id,))
if cur.fetchone()[0] == 0:
    # Record does not exist.
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO persons (id, username, points, score) VALUES (?,?,?,?);', (id,username,points,score)
else:
    # Record exists.
    cur.execute('UPDATE persons SET points=points+?, score=score+? WHERE id=?;', (points,score,id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.24.0 SQLite supports [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html):

```
sql = """
  INSERT INTO persons (id, username, points, score) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
  ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE
  SET points = points + EXCLUDED.points,
      score = score + EXCLUDED.score;
"""
cur.execute(sql, (id, username, points, score))
```

This will work assuming that `id` is unique.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/PGxQpzrf).